# I am wondering if there is an elegant way to apply either a combination of query, Arrayformula, sort, functions in Google Sheets to do the following

Tags: sql, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, sumifs

Google Sheets Problem.  I have a master list that has columns which are employers, job post, # of spots, parameter x, parameter y,...etc.

"Master Sheet" #a tab

```
Employers   Job       Spots
John        Cleaner   1  
Mike        Cleaner   2
John        Cleaner   3
John        Server    5
Alice       Cook      1
Dave        Cook      1
Mary        Cleaner   3
Alice       Server    5
Alice       Cleaner   2
Dave        Server    4
Mike        Server    3
Alice       Server    1
```

This is what I would like "Output Sheet" #another tab with two columns. 1st is Jobs and 2nd is # of employers that account for 80% of the jobs in that category plus any additional filters.  The idea is to give a single # that gives an 80/20 rule type metric.  The trick is to Sort one column from highest to lowest first.  I can do this but in multiple steps that seem annoyingly inefficient.  I wonder if there is a better way where I can put everything in one cell and drag down or do a query function.  The output looks like below.

```
Job      # of employers that account for ~80% of all the jobs in that category + filters
Cleaner ~3 
Cook     1
Server   ~3
```

#because total Cleaner jobs is 11.  80% is 8.8.  And sorting employers highest to lowest (after accounting for duplicates), 3 employers represent 80% of the Cleaner jobs available.  Server total is 21, 80% is 16.8, so ~3 employers represent 80% of the Server jobs available.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To take 80%:

```
=query(A15:C26, "Select B, sum(C)*8/100 group by B label B 'Job'")
```

you will get

```
{0.88, 0.16, 1.44)
```

But the next you can continue by yourself